# Modal outside of viewport on mobile

Tags: lightning-web-components, modal

I'm currently trying to use the modal from https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/modals on my LWC. My component has a lot lines and each line has a button that can open the modal. I want the modal to always be centered with the user viewport, but instead it always open on the center of the page and the user has to scroll down to see it. I also tried setting a height value for `slds-modal__container` but then the component is fixed at the top of the page instead of the middle.

Comment: Have you found the solution or a workaround?

Comment: @jm. No, I just stopped trying to use modal for mobile. The docs actually say that modal scroll is currently not supported for Salesforce1 Mobile.

Answer (score 1):

use this:

```html
 < div class="slds-modal__container" style='justify-content:flex-start' >
```

or You can `.focus()` to any form field, issue can be resolved in that way also.